# Any rake command is waiting few minutes before running within Docker For Mac container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, docker

Run simple docker architecture with 2 containers db and rails application. Any rake command related to db is very slow. Like `rake db:create`, `rake db:migrate`

Tried to test speed between 2 containers by iperf. It shows 26-27 Gbits/sec. So it looks like not network problem. And it is working like charm in any linux host.

```
Docker For Mac specs
MacOS Mojave 10.14.3;
Engine: 18.09.1;
Compose: 1.23.2;
Machine 0.16.1;
```

Here is sample docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  postgres_10_5:
    image: postgres:10.5
    ports:
      - "5432"
    networks:
      - backend


  web_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "1080:1080"
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=development
    volumes:
      - .:/home/app
    networks:
      - backend


networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

Expect not wait for result of any rake command around 5 minutes. Don't know where to dig down. Any hints?

Comment: run `docker logs -f rails_container_name` on the container name that is created from rails and then run your command.  Also it would be helpful if you added exact command you are using to invoke `rake` commands in the container

Comment: yeah, logs command shows logs from container, but actually it waits the same 5 minutes before sends response.

I am trying create database, or run migrations like usual:
`bundle exec rake db:create` . Nothing uncommon, but it works fast in linux.
Tried few month ago and got the same issue and switched docker development process to Linux machine. Thought that problem with MacOS and docker.
But people somehow developing docker architecture in MacOS, that is why I thinks might be some problems with my computer or settings.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same issue too. It's to do with the very poor performance of Docker on OSX, and how you've setup your volumes/mounts in docker.

I found [this article](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/ruby-on-whales-docker-for-ruby-rails-development) that has a good overview of how to setup a `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` for Rails, and have it actually perform OK.

The main thing to understand:

> To make Docker fast enough on MacOS follow these two rules: use :cached to mount source files and use volumes for generated content (assets, bundle, etc.).

You haven't setup your volumes properly for ruby gems, postgresql data (and possibly other things).

Key statements you need in your `Dockerfile`:

```
...

# Configure bundler and PATH
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 \
  GEM_HOME=/bundle \
  BUNDLE_JOBS=4 \
  BUNDLE_RETRY=3
ENV BUNDLE_PATH $GEM_HOME
ENV BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG=$BUNDLE_PATH \
  BUNDLE_BIN=$BUNDLE_PATH/bin
ENV PATH /app/bin:$BUNDLE_BIN:$PATH

# Upgrade RubyGems and install required Bundler version
RUN gem update --system && \
    gem install bundler:$BUNDLER_VERSION

# Create a directory for the app code
RUN mkdir -p /app
...
```

And in your `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'
postgres_10_5:
    image: postgres:10.5
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432"
web_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - .:/app:cached
      - rails_cache:/app/tmp/cache
      - bundle:/bundle
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV:-development}
    depends_on:
      - postgres_10_5
volumes:
  postgres:
  bundle:
  rails_cache:
```

See [the article](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/ruby-on-whales-docker-for-ruby-rails-development) for a more in-depth discussion on how it all works.